# smart pointers, typedefs and forward declarations

Tags: c++, typedef, smart-pointers

I love using smart pointers, and have seen a bit of code which makes nice use of `typedef`s make make them prettier. For example:

```
struct A {
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> pointer;
};
```

allows me to write: `A::pointer a(new A);`

But I have hit a minor snag in my `typedef` happiness :-/, forward declarations...

So imagine this scenario:

```
struct B;
struct A {
    boost::shared_ptr<B> b_;
};

struct B {
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a_;
};
```

works well enough, but I'd love to clean that up a little. Unfortunately, this is **doesn't work**

```
struct B;
struct A {
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> pointer;
    B::pointer b_; // <-- error here
};

struct B {
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<B> pointer;
    A::pointer a_;
};
```

I understand why, at that point in the file, the compiler has no information that B in fact has a type in it named `pointer`.

I have a feeling that I am stuck using the old approach at least for some stuff, but I'd love to hear some clever ideas.

Answer (score 6):

That use of typedefs doesn't make it prettier- it's worthless. You can make a `shared_ptr` to an incomplete type, so just use `shared_ptr<B>`.

Comment: Agree, just leave a comment that the rest of the code should use B::pointer, as the types will be equivalent

Answer (score 4):

If you want to share typedefs you probably want to use namespaces for declaring them:

```
struct A;
struct B;

namespace Aimpl {
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> pointer;
}

namespace Bimpl {
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<B> pointer;
}

struct A {
    Bimpl::pointer b_;
};

struct B {
    Aimpl::pointer a_;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two approaches:

- You could create a `ptr_for` template and use it something like this `ptr_for<B>::type b_ptr_;`
- You could pimpl the two structs (I know this probably isn't what you're looking for) so the definitions of the implementations can both appear after the definitions of `A` and `B`.